# Getting <br /> after implode function

Tags: php

i used php implode method to an array inside javascript.Yesterday it was working fine but now am getting  `SyntaxError: syntax error <br/>` in firebug.

I closed the php tag correctly but not sure why is this coming.

```
function create() {
    var sTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * (windowHeight));
       <?php 
        for ($i = 1; $ i <= 28; $i++) {
            if(${'h'.$i} != NULL) {
                $sel[] = ${'h'.$i};
            } 
        }              
        $format=  implode('","', $sel); ?>
        var selectedImg = new Array("<?php echo $format; ?>");
      }
```

I am getting 
 above the

```
var selectedImg = new Array("<?php echo $format; ?>");
```

when I viewed the JavaScript in FireBug.Can anyone help?

Comment: from the code provided there cannot be said anything about a mistake, pls provide more code

Comment: @sun Is your javascript in a separate file?

Comment: Let me guess before seeing the whole code...You get a single quote in that array that messes up your javascript...

Comment: No in same file.Check my edits @Ben Carey

Comment: can you show us what you get after php proccess ... are you sure that $sel is empty before this foreach and after it..

Comment: Array is created in php correctly.Only problem is in implode. I want those values into javascript array

Comment: when i remove `$format=  implode('","', $sel); ?>`  i'm not getting any bug

Comment: This line `SyntaxError: syntax error <br/>` is likely not the entire error. Look in the source and find the rest of the error.

Comment: Why don't you simply use JSON (`json_encode($sel);`) and use it with JS instead of uggly implode into JS Array?

Comment: Yesterday this was running good.okay i'll look into json.I don't know that here after only i have to take a look

Comment: You're probably getting PHP notice due to undefined variable. Together with html_errors set to true this will output some text which may contain <br />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fix ..

```
      function create() {
        var sTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * (windowHeight));
           <?php 
            $sel = array();
            for ($i = 1; $ i <= 28; $i++) {
                if(${'h'.$i} != NULL) {
                    $sel[] = ${'h'.$i};
                } 
            }              
            $format = !empty($sel) ? implode('","', $sel) : ""; ?>
            var selectedImg = new Array("<?php echo $format; ?>");
          }
```

Other method with json encode

```
      function create() {
        var sTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * (windowHeight));
           <?php 
            $sel = array();
            for ($i = 1; $ i <= 28; $i++) {
                if(${'h'.$i} != NULL) {
                    $sel[] = ${'h'.$i};
                } 
            }              
           ?>
            var selectedImg = <?php echo json_encode($sel); ?>;
          }
```

Comment: Thanks as you asked in comment `$sel` is empty because i didn't selected any option in admin interface which will set the values for `$sel`.This is the problem behind it.Yesterday it was checked that is why the confusion. @ Svetlio

Comment: By the way your json is not giving correct output. am gettin  

`var selectedImg = new Array("["1","8"]");` i believe it should be like this `var selectedImg = new Array("1","8");` in order to run without bug

Comment: why you set "new Array()" .. ? Its already array with json_encode >>

new Array("1","8") == [1,8]

Comment: oops thank you,JSON method too working. Is json used for this purpose alone or we can use any other